Tengo un Get que tiene 2 respuestas según la consulta, como puedo hacer que me enseñe las 2 opciones?
tengo este codigo en .NET
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TotalCheckService.Models
{
    public class ApiResponseAdeudo
    {
        public List<Adeudo> Data { get; set; }
        public List<Infraccion> Infracciones { get; set; }
    }

    public class Adeudo
    {
        public string Folio { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Situacion { get; set; }
        public string Motivo { get; set; }
        public string Fundamento { get; set; }
        public string Sancion { get; set; }
        public double Importe { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApiResponseInfracciones
    {
        public List<Infraccion> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Infraccion
    {
        public string Folio { get; set; }
        public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
        public string Situacion { get; set; }
        public string Motivo { get; set; }
        public string Fundamento { get; set; }
        public string Sancion { get; set; }
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }
        public double Importe { get; set; }
        public string LineaCaptura { get; set; }
        public string Vigencia { get; set; }
        public string Unid { get; set; }
    }
}

uso esta función para regresar el GET dependiendo de la información
En este código, verificamos si el JSON contiene la clave "adeudos_tenencia". Si lo hace, sabemos que la respuesta es para adeudos de tenencia y la deserializamos en ApiResponseAdeudo. Si no contiene esa clave, asumimos que la respuesta es para infracciones y la deserializamos en ApiResponseInfracciones
WebMethod
public string AdeudosTenencia(string placa)
{
    try
    {
        string urlAdeudosTenencia = $"/{placa}/adeudos";
        HttpWebRequest requestAdeudosTenencia = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAdeudosTenencia);
        requestAdeudosTenencia.Method = "GET";
        requestAdeudosTenencia.Headers["Authorization"] = BearerToken ?? RefreshToken();

        using (HttpWebResponse responseAdeudosTenencia = (HttpWebResponse)requestAdeudosTenencia.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader readerAdeudosTenencia = new StreamReader(responseAdeudosTenencia.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string jsonResponseAdeudosTenencia = readerAdeudosTenencia.ReadToEnd();

                // Deserializar el JSON en un objeto dinámico
                dynamic responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponseAdeudosTenencia);

                // Verificar si la clave "adeudos_tenencia" está presente en el objeto dinámico
                if (responseData != null && responseData.data != null && responseData.data.adeudos_tenencia != null)
                {
                    var apiResponseAdeudosTenencia = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponseAdeudo>(jsonResponseAdeudosTenencia);
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiResponseAdeudosTenencia);
                }
                else // Si no contiene la clave, asumir que contiene infracciones
                {
                    var apiResponseInfracciones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponseInfracciones>(jsonResponseAdeudosTenencia);
                    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(apiResponseInfracciones);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        return $"Error: {ex.Message}";
    }
}

si mis respuestas son algua de estas 2
Respuesta 1
{
    "data": {
        "adeudos_tenencia": [],
        "infracciones": [
            {
                "folio": "123456789A",
                "fecha": "2023-03-20",
                "situacion": "PAGADA",
                "motivo": "EXCESO DE VELOCIDAD",
                "fundamento": "EL LÍMITE DE VELOCIDAD ES: 70 km/h. VELOCIDAD DETECTADA: 82 km/h",
                "sancion": null
            }
        ]
    }
}

Respuesta 2
{
    "data": {
        "adeudos_tenencia": [
            2023,
            2024
        ],
        "infracciones": []
    }
}

OJO SOLO ME REGRESA 1 RESPUESTA NO PUEDEN SER LAS 2
que otra opcion me pueden dar, o que estoy haciendo mal?
Actualizacion
cuando lo corro me sale est0
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TotalCheckService.Models.Adeudo]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'data.adeudos_tenencia', line 1, position 28.'

entonces no se que esta pasando y cuando lo debugeuo siempre entra en el primer if

No entiendo el problema

Yo estoy igual que yuseff, no entiendo cual es realmente el problema o que es lo que buscas. Por empezar el GET tiene una única respuesta que entiendo es l descripta por el objeto de tipo ApiResponseInfracciones, dependiendo de la consulta obtienes ciertos datos u otros, pero la respueta es siempre ApiResponseInfracciones.  ¿qué quieres? ¿hacer dos consultas y "unir" las respuestas  en un nuevo objeto?

Disculpenme no lo detalle correctactamente.

Sigo sin entender :S. Lo primero que me gustaría que aclararas, es que según veo tu API consume otra API, esa respuesta tú la deserializary la vuelves a serializar para retornarla (y ahí te da un error), pero porque no retornas directamente la respuesta de la API, que ya es un JSON?????

Por curiosidad, ¿cómo va a saber el cliente la forma de deserializar cualquiera de los dos resultados?

No es necesario que realices la serializacion
Podes devolver un object directamente o devolver un IActionResult
Y en el return pones return Ok(ObjetoADevolver)

Creo que Enrique usa una versión de .net anterior a IActionResult

Estoy usando .net 4.6
